# Springboot/Thyme leaf exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm a beginner at Springboot, so decided to work on a shopping cart. Can't seem to find the root of org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null. nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.userPrincipal.name" (template: "/_header" - line 11, col 48)] with root cause

I already tried to check if the object in question is null

```
if (userDetails != null){
   model.addAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
}
```

The user class is abstract by the way using "import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;"

The particular HTML code:

```
<div class="header-bar">
    <th:block sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
      Hello
      <a th:href="@{/admin/accountInfo}" 
         th:utext="${#request.userPrincipal.name}">..</a>
         &nbsp;|&nbsp;
      <a th:href="@{/admin/logout}">Logout</a>
   </th:block>

   <th:block sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
     <a th:href="@{/admin/login}">Login</a>
   </th:block>
 </div>
```

And my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/admin/accountInfo" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accountInfo(Model model) {

    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());
    System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());
    System.out.println(userDetails.isEnabled());

     model.addAttribute("userDetails", userDetails);
     return "accountInfo";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `request.userPrincipal.name` is null. Check carefully request object. Where do you create it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the property again. `property="principal.username"`. Principle has the property `username` 
Ref: [See this tutorial for reference](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security)